# Likelihood Fitting in Mathematica

Tags: fitting

I'm trying to experiment a bit (for fun) with different approaches to fitting data sets. One aspect in particular is fitting data which has non-Gaussian noise. From what I have read, and questions on this site, likelihood evaluation seems to be the way to go.

I have set up a small example of some data which follows a Lorentz profile, but the noise is drawn from a Rayleigh Distribution. I choose a Rayleigh as it is a one parameter distribution.

```
LorentzFunction[A_, x0_, g_, nf_, x_] := A g^2/((x - x0)^2 + g^2) + nf

fspan = 50;
FFTLines = 800;
df = fspan/FFTLines;
fcentre = 1000;
fstart = fcentre - fspan/2;
fstop = fcentre + fspan/2;

NoisedLorentz = 
Table[
        {x, RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[LorentzFunction[10, 1000, 0.5, 3, x]]]}, {x, fstart, fstop, df}
    ];
```

I the try to calculate the log-likelihood:

```
LLH = LogLikelihood[RayleighDistribution[\[Sigma]], (#[[2]] - LorentzFunction[A, x0, g, nf, #[[2]]] ) & /@ NoisedLorentz];
```

This seems to compute fine. It's the next step I have a problem with. As I understand it, I need to maximise this function so I try:

```
FindMaximum[{LLH[[1, 1, 1]]}, {{A, 10}, {x0, 1000}, {g, 0.5}, {nf, 3}}]
```

This doesn't return anything at all. What am I doing wrong.

I'd like to be able to extract parameters using this method and then make some kind of precision/error estimation on these values -- in a similar way we do with Least squares fitting.

Comment: It produces errors for me. Try putting some constraints on as many of the parameters as possible, including `\[Sigma]` which is missing from your parameter list.

Comment: I removed the `bayesian` tag as I don't see anything resembling a Bayesian approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track but there are two issues.

The main issue is that there isn't a single Rayleigh distribution as indicated by your use of `RayleighDistribution[σ]` in the `LogLikelihood` function.  That should be replaced by `RayleighDistribution[LorentzFunction[A, x0, g, nf, #[[1]]]]`.

The second issue is that there is some "numerical instability" that seems to be associated with how good the starting values are.  First is shown how to perform the calculations when one has good starting values.

```
LorentzFunction[A_, x0_, g_, nf_, x_] := A g^2/((x - x0)^2 + g^2) + nf

fspan = 50;
FFTLines = 800;
df = fspan/FFTLines;
fcentre = 1000;
fstart = fcentre - fspan/2;
fstop = fcentre + fspan/2;

SeedRandom[12345];
NoisedLorentz = Table[{x, LorentzFunction[10, 1000, 0.5, 3, x], 
    RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[LorentzFunction[10, 1000, 0.5, 3, x]]]}, 
    {x, fstart, fstop, df}];

(* Log of likelihood *)
logL = Total[LogLikelihood[RayleighDistribution[LorentzFunction[A, x0, g, nf, #[[1]]]],
  {#[[3]]}] & /@ NoisedLorentz];

(* Maximum likelihood estimation *)
mle = FindMaximum[logL, {{A, 10}, {x0, 1000}, {g, 0.4}, {nf, 2.8}}]
(* {-1659.7, {A -> 9.06149, x0 -> 999.982, g -> 0.493172, nf -> 2.98831}} *)

(* Estimate of covariance matrix and standard errors *)
cov = -Inverse[(D[logL, {{A, x0, g, nf}, 2}]) /. mle[[2]]];
{ASE, x0SE, gSE, nfSE} = Diagonal[cov]^0.5
(* {2.10585, 0.0852092, 0.106067, 0.0577906} *)

(* Estimate of correlation matrix *)
cor = Table[cov[[i, j]]/Sqrt[cov[[i, i]] cov[[j, j]]], {i, Length[cov]},
  {j, Length[cov]}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Correlation matrix]

Now consider modifying just the starting value of `x0` from 1000 to 980:

```
mle = FindMaximum[logL, {{A, 10}, {x0, 980}, {g, 0.4}, {nf, 2.8}}]
(* {-1787.53, {A -> 9.97011, x0 -> 980.056, g -> -4.32762*10^-11, nf -> 3.44085}} *)
cov = -Inverse[(D[logL, {{A, x0, g, nf}, 2}]) /. mle[[2]]];
```

[image: Warning message]

```
cor = Table[cov[[i, j]]/Sqrt[cov[[i, i]] cov[[j, j]]], {i, Length[cov]}, 
  {j, Length[cov]}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Bogus correlation matrix]

Note that the estimate of the parameter correlation matrix is nonsensical.

The moral is:  good starting values are extremely important and things like correlation matrices need to be examined as any iteration procedure can go crazy.

Comment: Thanks for this @JimB! Do you think you could expand a little on your second comments? If I want to estimate all four parameters what is the best approach (I can ask this as a second question if you think it's appropriate)? Do you know of any tutorials on this kind of fitting/evaluation in M?

Comment: I played around with your solution and made it estimate all four parameters and while it completes with reasonable values I get a `AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal` error. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: Did you look at the correlation matrix of your solution with all four parameters?  I was getting perfect correlation between two of the parameter estimators and very high correlations with the others.  This suggests over-parameterization given the combination of the model and available data.

Comment: Okay I think I see what you mean now. This probably deviates away from my original question, but what can one do in this situation? If you know the noise comes from a distribution and you know that your data follows a specific function. If the noise isn't gauss then least-squares fitting seems to be inappropriate and from what I have read, likelihood evaulations always seem to be the best approach if you have the computing ability?

Comment: Hmmm.  I must have done something wrong earlier when I was getting correlations of 1.0.  I started from scratch and got reasonable results after that.  Sorry about that.  I'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: Ahh!  Figured out why (or at least how) I got correlations of 1.0:  The results can strongly depend on the starting values.  That will be part of the update.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to modify your answer! I have accepted your answer as you solved the problem I gave. I have an additional question: Is this a good approach to solving this type of problem? If not how would you approach it? Could this be better done with a Bayesian approach?

Comment: I would use the term "alternative approaches" as you would be getting two different things between the Bayesian and Frequentist approach.  If you go the Bayesian route, you'd need to come up with a prior joint distribution for the parameters.  Can you (as opposed to "are you willing to") come up with a prior joint distribution for the parameters?  I'm more in the middle of which route to go.  If you have lots of data, go the maximum likelihood route.  If you don't have much data AND have knowledge as to the likely values of the parameters, then go Bayesian.